# Force page break before and after in XSL:FO

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

How can I force a page break before and after an `<fo:block>` element when the following condition holds true:

- Content does not fit onto previous page in its entirety.

I have tried using `keep-together.within-page` and `page-break-inside` however (in both cases) when the content spans longer than a single page (vertically), everything gets squashed up.

Comment: What value do you use for keep-together.within-page? If it is "always", does it get any better if you relax the strength of the keep condition by specifying a numeric value (for example 1)?

Comment: @mzjn Yes I specified `always` which caused the output to squash to fit into page. The following numeric values (which I do not understand at all) did absolutely nothing (didn't even squash onto page) 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, 100, 200.

Comment: The FO specification allows for varying "strengths" of keep conditions (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#keepbreak). I was under the impression that at least some rudiment of this was implemented in FOP, but I may be wrong about that. What version of FOP do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_break-before.asp) and [break-after](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_break-after.asp) attributes with the value 'page'?